# warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous. I have No branch or tag Named "HEAD"

Tags: git

I am new to Git,when I executed the following command:

```
git status
```

I got  this message:

```
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
....
```

If I executed

```
git branch -a
```

I got the following:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

When executed this:

```
git show-ref
```

Got this:

```
64b0e322f945691e8365a0c1b5f93d6584cde4a5 refs/FETCH_HEAD
e4fcd3322fb3cf4eb5b369c62e99073d60afec74 refs/HEAD
e4fcd3322fb3cf4eb5b369c62e99073d60afec74 refs/heads/master
e5408db40c31909d50c25f60146499b09746b84b refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I'm in China, you know , the Network always unstable,was it related to some transport error when pull from remote repo?

Thansk A Lot!

Comment: Type `cat .git/HEAD` and let us know what you see.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `cat .git/HEAD` shows 
`ref: refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have both a `.git/refs/HEAD` file and a `.git/HEAD` file.  The `.git/HEAD` file must always be present (and the contents you showed in a comment are reasonable).  The `.git/refs/HEAD` file probably should not exist at all, but it's not clear what created it.

(The file `.git/refs/FETCH_HEAD` also should not exist, and again it's not clear what created it.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I resolve this problem? del these two file in .git directory? Or any command can help me ?

Comment: It's certainly possible to delete the `refs/HEAD` and `refs/FETCH_HEAD` references (either manually or by using `git update-ref -d refs/HEAD` and `git update-ref -d refs/FETCH_HEAD`, but before you do, it would be interesting to (a) see what's in them and (b) try to figure out what created them (e.g., are they time-stamped differently and can you identify what was happening at around that time? do they have reflogs?).

Comment: Through time-stamp I found a post-commit hook file created right before the time  refs/FETCH_HEAD and refs/HEAD file created.The hook file was from gitbook in order to sync webBook when check in .md file.

Comment: after executed  two `git update-ref` command you mentioned before, HEAD and FETCH_HEAD file still there.I pull from remote repo ,there were some conflicts ,Are they  associated with this problem?

Comment: No, pull (merge or rebase) conflicts would not be related to this.  Note, though that `.git/HEAD` *should* (in fact must) exist, and `.git/FETCH_HEAD` is normal, it's the `.git/refs/HEAD` and `.git/refs/FETCH_HEAD` references that are not normal.